# How to get a list of all members of a specific role in a discord server?

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of all the members who have the role in a discord server? Is it possible to just do in dev tools in chrome, by executing a command in it to get the list?

Is possible to get them all by discord name/tag, or only member ID?

Basically I need the full member list from a specific role of 1 discord server, what would be the best way to go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried yet so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop like this:

```py
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if role in member.roles:
        members.append(member)
```

There is no in-built method to do this.